# Inject Laravel Input property into Mockery session object

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm working on an existing Laravel app and trying to start building out a test suite for it.  I'm using the Mockery library to mock the dependencies of the class I'm testing but I've hit a roadblock I can't seem to get around.

```
$leadRepositoryInterface = m::mock('CRM\Storage\Lead\LeadRepositoryInterface');
$response = m::mock('ColorJar\ApiResponse\Response');

$object = new LeadsController($leadRepositoryInterface, $response);
```

I get an error when I run the preceding code because the parent class of LeadsController checks Input::all()[__currentUser] and crashes because Input::all() returns nothing.

I need to set the Laravel Input facade variable(I'm sure I'm misusing terminology there, sorry) to any user in my system but I don't see anywhere in the Mockery docs on how to set a property of a mocked object, I only see how to set expectations and return values.  How would I do this?  Will Laravel allow me to set the return of Input::all()?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock the response from the Input facade but you can mock the underlying class which is `Request`. You would then do something like this:

```
Request::shouldReceive('input->all')->andReturn('someValue');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had to move over to another project for a bit but I'll try this when I get back to this.  At first glance though, this seems like it'll work for my purposes.  Thanks!  I'll accept your answer when I'm able to test this.